# Express rest api call with angular 2 How to

Tags: rest, angular

Greeting, 
I have a trivial issue on calling a rest api from angular 2.
I have a rest api endpoint:

```
api/room/byName/:roomName
```

if I use restfull tools like postman etc and call api `http://localhost:3000/api/room/byName/roomname1` this works fine and get result.
But when i can call this from angular2 , the rest api is not even being called.

```
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('roomName', roomName);
  return this
  .http
  .get('/api/room/byName',{search:params})
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

I am sure, I am not calling it properly. Appreciate your help on how to call it from angular 2.

Thanks

> Edit

After getting advice this is my code now but still no luck:
Angular call:

```
    return this.http
  .get('/api/room/byName/'+roomName)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Express endpoint:

```
var rooms = express.Router();
rooms.get('/byName/:roomName', function(req,res){

var roomn = req.params.roomName;
console.log('Looking by roomName: ' + roomn);
Room.findOne({ "roomName": roomn }, function(err, rooms) {
    if (err) {

        next(err);
     } else {

        res.json(rooms);
     }
 });

});
```

This works fine if i call the endpoint from browser:
http://localhost:3000/api/room/byName/test

Comment: could you provide your express implement

Comment: Arer you subscribing to the observable?

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: no errors at all.. this endpoint works fine when it is called from browser : http://localhost:3000/api/room/byName/test

Comment: add in the question not comment @leo

Comment: put the complete url in get function

Comment: complete url ? you mean http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/room/byName/'+roomName)

Comment: yes.. try that ..

Comment: capture your console tab

Comment: this is strange.. the url is not even working from code... its working outside..

Comment: i have several other calls on room api all are working.. for example:return this
      .http
      .post('/api/room', room)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());

Comment: return this
      .http
      .get('/api/room/all')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Http get](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#get-anchor) takes only url and not body as parameter.It is not a post to have body.

Try:

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('roomName', roomName);
  return this
  .http
  .get(`/api/room/byName/${roomName}`)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: yes.. but the http function 'get' does not have a separate parameter which takes it..They should be included in the url.Check the api link in the answer.

Comment: I have specifically said it is not post to have body and it takes only url.I am not sure how they will think the opposite..OP was calling get and passing search params as a separate parameter like body parameter in post. I just specified the parameter is not available

Answer (score 2):

first make sure you're enabled [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

2nd: change this

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('roomName', roomName);
return this
  .http
  .get('/api/room/byName',{search:params})
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

to:

```
return this
  .http
  .get('/api/room/byName/'+ roomName)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```